# Where does AzureML run its analytics?

Tags: azure, bigdata, azure-machine-learning-service

If I have data in a Hadoop Cluster or SQL Elastic DB, is ML bringing that data onto ML servers, or leaving it on Hadoop/sql and running its analysis there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Azure Machine Learning will bring that data onto ML servers.

Answer (score 0):

Execution for each of the modules is done on AzureML's backend servers. But you can connect to the databases through either "Reader" modules, or say Python code using ODBC to issue queries to a database and get the results as the return type, in which case the query is being down on the data servers, and the results are sent to AzureML. This is useful if you want to do a data aggregation queries in Hive or SQL to reduce the size of your dataset before bringing it into AzureML.